# JQuery how to retrieve json result form jqXHR object

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.5

I've got the following situation:

```
$.when(jsonCall1(),jsonCall2())
    .then(function(a,b){
        var json1 = a[2].responseText;
        var json2 = b[2].responseText;

        --- Do some stuff with these json responses ---
    })
    .fail(function(){
        console.log( 'failed requests...');
    });
}

var jsonCall1 = function(){ 
    return $.getJSON('http://myURL/1');
}

var jsonCall2 = function(){ 
    return $.getJSON('http://myURL/2');
}
```

I'm using the deferred objects to do some chaining of methods. This all works like a charm, but the responseText values i get back from the jqXHR object `a[2]` and `b[2]` return plain strings. One solution is to just call `$.parseJSON()` on the strings, but I guess there must be a better way to do this.

In other words, can I get a direct JSON object from the jqXHR object when using `$.getJSON()` with `$when().then()`?

Comment: Guess there is no better way to do it. Anyway thank you JMax for editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess that there is no better way of doing this.